# Equivalent codes

Tags: coding-theory

I'm having problems by understanding the use one can do of equivalent codes. To solve problems about a linear code with a generator matrix G, can I always assume that the matrix is in systematic form (ie (id|R))?

Which are the features of equivalent codes in general? Thanks

Comment: Any linear code is equivalent to a code which has a generator matrix in systematic form, but not every linear code has a generator matrix in systematic form. Does this help?

Comment: May be... So if I want to prove something about any (n,k) linear codes, can I always assume that it's generator is in systematic form?

Comment: No, equivalence of codes doesn't preserve everything, but it preserves a lot of interesting things like length, dimension, size and minimum distance.

Comment: Agree with Git Gud.