# properties of a non systematic code we can extract from his "systematic" version

Tags: coding-theory

Given a non systematic linear code matrix representation $G_{ns}$ (k rows and n columns) we say that the codeword $c$ is equal to

$c=vG_{ns}$

(where $v$ is the input sequence)

Is it ALWAYS possible to transform $G_{ns}$ into a systematic code $G_{sys}$ (that is $G_{sys}$ can be expressed ad $[I_k | P]$, $P$ is a generic k rows and r=n-k columns) ?

If yes what are the operations we have to perform?

If we have now $G_{sys}$ and we calculate its related quantities ($d_{min}$, distances profile, multiplicities ) what are the relationships between these quantities and the same quantities calculated on $G_{ns}$ ?

Comment: It's not always possible, consider for instance $G=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Regarding the last question, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110379/equivalent-codes#comment2264424_1110379) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on what you mean by "transform". For any linear code $C$, there is a code $D$ that is [permutation equivalent](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/coding-notes/node7.html) to $C$ and has a systematic generator matrix.

Suppose $C$ has generator matrix $G_{ns}$. Let $G'_{ns}$ be the reduced row echelon form of $G_{ns}$. Swap columns in $G'_{ns}$ to produce a new matrix $G_{sys} = [I_k | P]$. Then the code $D = \{x G_{sys} \mid x \in F^k\}$ is systematic and permutation equivalent to $C$.

As noted in the comment by Git Gud, length, dimension, size, and minimum distance are all preserved.

Comment: thank you. Is there anything we can say about distances profile?
I am very new to this subject so i don't know if my technical language is correct: by distances profile i mean the set of values that correspond to the distances from every codeword with respect to the all zero codeword

Comment: That's also preserved by permutation equivalence. I don't know of a preexisting term for that set, but 'distances profile' seems like a reasonable name for it.